# Implement SearchBox using Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ado.net, search-box

I am new to ASP.NET, I am making a search box in my application Using AJAX.

For example: if a user enters "abc" in the textbox, then the textbox will fetch data from the database which starts with "abc".

but, i am unable to see data,

Here is my code snippet:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SearchBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="SearchBox" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getdata()
     {

         var connection = new ActiveXObject("System.Data.SqlClient");

         var connectionstring = "Data Source=ilsql;Initial Catalog=krunal_DB;User ID=krunaldbuser;Password=krunal@2012;Provider=System.Data.SqlClient";

        connection.Open(connectionstring);
        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

        rs.Open("SELECT DISTINCT Scrip FROM dbo.SearchBoxData where Scrip Like '{0}%'", TextBox1.Text, connection);
        rs.MoveFirst
        while (!rs.eof) {

            document.write(rs.fields(1));
            rs.movenext;
        }

        rs.close;
        connection.close;





            var xmlhttp;
            if (str.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.asp?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

    }
</script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup="getdata()"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Any Help will be Appriciated.***

**Thanks In Advance !!**

Comment: Why dont you use AutoComplete Textbox from AjaxControlToolkit ? its really easy to use and configure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you try AutoCompleteExtender of AjaxControlToolkit. find the : [demo here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
runat="server" 
ID="autoComplete1" 
TargetControlID="myTextBox"
ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
CompletionInterval="1000"
EnableCaching="true"
CompletionSetCount="20" 
CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
    <Animations>
        <OnShow> ... </OnShow>
        <OnHide> ... </OnHide>
    </Animations>
```

Comment: i dont have much knowledge in this AJAX..... m new to this technology, where to write my query and how to open db connection ?